# User registration form validation in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fapi, drupal-forms

Drupal 7 comes with the built-in user registration form (user/register). I use this form for new users to register. Which is quite obvious. Now the problem is, and I find it hard to believe that it isn't there, I need some validating.

When a new user completes the form and hits submit, the account is being created. Good.

**But**: when a user completes the form and hits submit, but the **email address or username is already in use**, the pages just reloads and the user is not being created, which is good, but theres no warning on what he has to change in the form what so ever.

I find it strange that this is not standard.

Could anyone provide me some help? I really have no clue...

Answer (score 2):

Use can achieve that with many approaches.

Here's an example using [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)()

```
function [YOUR_MODULE]_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if($form_id == "user_register_form" || $form_id == "user_profile_form")
    {
        $form['#validate'][] = '_your_custom_validation_callback';
    }
}

function _your_custom_validation_callback(&$form_state)
{
    // use your validation code...
}
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.